# Choice-Dependent Drop Down Menus on iOS

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I'm working on an app that has one major feature that is a giant pain in the rear, at least for me, a novice part-time developer.  I am working on having the user select an area within Thailand.

The way I am doing this is having them first choose the province, then based on that, they choose a region from within that province, then a district, and finally a sub-district. I have a spreadsheet that has this all laid out, but my mind is just completely lost on getting it converted into this drop down menu file system in iOS to be able to go from the general to the specific.

Comment: So what is your problem, to design the drop down or to filter out the data to show in the drop down?

Comment: @Janmenjaya Filtering out.  I can create the needed 4 UIPickerviews just fine, and know how to populate, but getting all the data in there, so that when one province is selected, only the regions within that are available with the next, and so and on so forth.

Comment: Just look at your data, You must have some id for places. for an example
Lets say provinence id, district id, sub-district id.
So the districts coming under certain provinence must have the same provinence id, so you can filter out by using predicate..
If you still need any help, you need to share the doc.

Comment: @Janmenjaya Sorry been a little while, the file in question is http://www.316apps.com/Fritch/dropdown.xlsx